# OpenGL Issues whenever using depth attachment on FBO

Tags: opengl, opentk, fbo, depth-buffer

What I'm trying to do is to actually implement an object picking routine, and for now i decided to do that by rendering the scene to a texture using specific object colors and read the appropriate pixels to identify the object.

The problem is that I used an external fbo to accomplish that, and I found out that by default Depth information is not used in the new fbo render. Searching on the web I think this is the case unless there is something bound to the fbo's depth attachment (either a texture or a renderbuffer).

So I tried both of those solutions, but whenever I'm trying to attach either a new renderbuffer (using glFramebufferRenderbuffer) or a texture (using glFramebufferTexture) there is nothing written in the fbo. I check that by reading the fbo's pixels and they are all zeros...

Here is my code for that procedure (using OpenTK) that tries to use the depth renderbuffer and attach it to the fbo

```
//First of all clear the color buffer
//Create the texture to render to
int tex_w = glControl1.Width;
int tex_h = glControl1.Height;

//Create Frame and renderbuffers
int fb = GL.GenFramebuffer();
int depth_rb = GL.GenRenderbuffer();
//int color_rb = GL.GenRenderbuffer();


GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, fb);
GL.Viewport(0, 0, tex_w, tex_h);
//Clear the buffer and enable depth test
GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
GL.DepthMask(true);

//Create Color texture
int out_tex = GL.GenTexture();
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, out_tex);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, tex_w, tex_h, 0, PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.UnsignedByte, IntPtr.Zero);

//Create Depth texture
//int depth_tex = GL.GenTexture();
//GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, depth_tex);
//GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.Clamp);
//GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.Clamp);
//GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest);
//GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Nearest);
//GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.DepthComponent32, tex_w, tex_h, 0, PixelFormat.DepthComponent, PixelType.Float, IntPtr.Zero);


//Attach Textures to this FBO
GL.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0, TextureTarget.Texture2D, out_tex, 0);
//GL.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.DepthAttachment, TextureTarget.Texture2D, depth_tex, 0);

//Bind depth renderbuffer
GL.BindRenderbuffer(RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, depth_rb);
GL.RenderbufferStorage(RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, RenderbufferStorage.DepthComponent16, tex_w, tex_h);
GL.FramebufferRenderbuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.DepthAttachment, RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, depth_rb);


GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, fb);
GL.DrawBuffer(DrawBufferMode.ColorAttachment0);
//Now render objects with the picking program
if (this.mainScene != null) traverse_render(this.mainScene, 2);

//Check
if (GL.CheckFramebufferStatus(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer) != FramebufferErrorCode.FramebufferComplete)
    Debug.WriteLine("FRAMEBUFFER Issues" + GL.CheckFramebufferStatus(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer));



//Store Framebuffer to Disk
byte[] pixels = new byte[4 * tex_w * tex_h];


//GL.ReadBuffer(ReadBufferMode.None);
//Debug.WriteLine("Saving Picking Buffer. Dimensions: " + tex_w + " " + tex_h);
//GL.ReadPixels(0, 0, tex_w, tex_h, PixelFormat.DepthComponent, PixelType.UnsignedByte, pixels);
//FileStream ds = new FileStream("pickDepthBuffer", FileMode.Create);
//BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(ds);
//bw.Write(pixels);
//ds.Flush();
//ds.Close();


GL.ReadBuffer(ReadBufferMode.ColorAttachment0);
Debug.WriteLine("Saving Picking Buffer. Dimensions: " + tex_w +" "+ tex_h);
GL.ReadPixels(0, 0, tex_w, tex_h, PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.UnsignedByte, pixels);
FileStream fs = new FileStream("pickBuffer", FileMode.Create);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
bw.Write(pixels);
fs.Flush();
fs.Close();

//Pick object here :)
GL.ReadBuffer(ReadBufferMode.ColorAttachment0);
Debug.WriteLine("Selecting Object at Position: " + p.X + " " + (tex_h -p.Y));
byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
GL.ReadPixels(p.X, tex_h - p.Y, 1, 1, PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.UnsignedByte, buffer);

//Convert color to id
int ob_id = (buffer[1] << 8) | buffer[0];

//Deselect everything first
traverse_oblist_rs(this.mainScene, "selected", 0);

//Try to find object
traverse_oblist_field<int>(this.mainScene, ob_id, "selected", 1);

//Restore Rendering Buffer
GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, 0);

//Cleanup
GL.DeleteFramebuffer(fb);
//GL.DeleteRenderbuffer(color_rb);
GL.DeleteRenderbuffer(depth_rb);
GL.DeleteTexture(out_tex);
//GL.DeleteTexture(depth_tex);
pixels = null;
```

Commenting the lines

```
GL.FramebufferRenderbuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.DepthAttachment, RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, depth_rb);
```

or

```
GL.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachment.DepthAttachment, TextureTarget.Texture2D, depth_tex, 0);
```

resolves the problems but the no depth problem remains of course.

In addition to that I tried placing GL.GetErrors everywhere in the code to notify me of any issues but every single call returns NoError....

Am I missing something obvious here? Or at least is there any other way that I can debug that?

Comment: As you don't clear you depth buffer (you only try to _before_ creating it), and you are just using an unitialized texture or renderbuffer, there is some high probability that it is all zeros and your depth test is failing for every fragment.